# Weird multiplicator operator behavior in a two arrays to hash combination

Tags: ruby

I was looking for a way to convert two arrays into a single hash. I found something like this :

```
a1 = [1,2,3]
a2 = [?A, ?B, ?C]
Hash[*a1.zip(a2).flatten]
```

I thought that this syntax was a bit weird, because `Hash[a1.zip a2]` would do exactly the same. But more than that, I don't understand the need for the `*` operator.

I know that it turns objects into arrays, or something alike (but not in the same way `[]` does, apparently).

When I execute :

```
a = a1.zip(a2).flatten
 => [1, "A", 2, "B", 3, "C"]
a = *a1.zip(a).flatten
 => [1, "A", 2, "B", 3, "C"]
```

Nothing really happens, and for what I know of the `*` operator, this seems to be the normal behavior.

So, why does

```
Hash[*a1.zip(a2).flatten]
 => {1=>"A", 2=>"B", 3=>"C"}
Hash[a1.zip(a).flatten]
 => {}
```

Return different values, given that the parameters seem identical ?

I guess I must be missing something about the `*` operator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `*` operator is used with arrays like that it is called the **splat operator**.

Think of it as **an operator that removes the first level of brackets around an array**. This is quite useful because you can turn arrays into argument lists:

```
def stuff(x, y, z)
end

a = [1, 2, 3]
stuff(*a) # x,y,z gets assigned 1,2,3
```

The same thing works with `Hash[]`. The `[]` operator on `Hash` accepts as arguments:

1. An argument list of key-value pairs:
   `Hash["a", 1, "b", 2] #=> { "a" => 1, "b" => 2 }`
2. An array or array pairs representing key-values:
   `Hash[ [["a", 1], ["b", 2]] ] #=> { "a" => 1, "b" => 2 }`

`Hash[]` not does NOT accept a plain flat array as arguments:

```
Hash[ ["a", 1, "b", 2] ] #=> {}
```

So with this in mind, plus our understanding what the splat operator does you can now see what is happening:

```
paired_array = a1.zip(a2)
=> [[1, "A"], [2, "B"], [3, "C"]]

plain_array = a1.zip(a2).flatten
=> [1, "A", 2, "B", 3, "C"]

# Per rule 2 above we know this works
Hash[paired_array]
=> {1=>"A", 2=>"B", 3=>"C"} 

# This won't work
Hash[plain_array]
=> {}

# But if we turn the plain_array into an argument list, 
# then we know per rule 1 above that this will work
Hash[*plain_array]
=> {1=>"A", 2=>"B", 3=>"C"}
```

Now then you might be wondering what the hey is happening when you do:

```
a = *plain_array
=> [1, "A", 2, "B", 3, "C"]
```

Since we know the splat operator effectively strips the brackets, we get this:

```
a = 1, "A", 2, "B", 3, "C"
```

...which funnily enough is valid Ruby code and just creates an array again.

You can read more fun stuff about the splat operator in the [rubyspec test case for the splat operator](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/language/splat_spec.rb).

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a mistake in your example, it should be like this:

```
Hash[a1.zip(a2).flatten] #=> {}
Hash[*a1.zip(a2).flatten] #=> {1=>"A", 2=>"B", 3=>"C"}
```

The splat operator in the assign mode converts an array to multiple arguments:

```
duck, cow, pig = *["quack","mooh","oing"] #=> ["quack","mooh","oing"]
```

Actually it's identical to

```
duck, cow, pig = ["quack","mooh","oing"] #=> ["quack","mooh","oing"]
```

But from the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) you can see that Hash[...] receives multiple arguments, so the splat operator helps to assign each of those multiple arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that mysterious:

```
a1 = [1,2,3]
a2 = [?A, ?B, ?C]

p Hash[*a1.zip(a2).flatten] #{1=>"A", 2=>"B", 3=>"C"}
```

The `*` converts the array to a mere list (of arguments).

But why wasn't this syntax used?

```
p Hash[a1.zip(a2)]# {1=>"A", 2=>"B", 3=>"C"}
```

Well, it is new since Ruby 1.9.2. Your example is probably older.

Comment: Oh, that was an old example, okay ! Thanks :)